# Using TryInto generics with anyhow::Error

Tags: generics, rust, error-handling

The function is expected to accept a command which can be converted to a string, and also I am using anyhow to handle the error thing.
Here is the code:

```
pub fn converter<T: TryInto<String>>(input: T) -> Result<String>
where
    T::Error: Into<anyhow::Error>,
{
    // error here
    // the trait bound `<T as TryInto<std::string::String>>::Error: StdError` is not satisfied
    // required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<<T as TryInto<std::string::String>>::Error>` for `anyhow::Error`
    // required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, <T as TryInto<std::string::String>>::Error>>` for `Result<std::string::String, anyhow::Error>
    let out_str = input.try_into()?;
    Ok(out_str)
}
```

I have added a type restriction for `T::Error` as `T::Error: Into<anyhow::Error>`, hope the compiler can do the error handling, but shows the `T::Error` can't be convert to a `anyhow::Error`.

The type restriction is referred from: https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow/issues/172, but I still can't figure out how to use the `TryInto` generic with anyhow.

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Replace `T::Error: Into<anyhow::Error>` with `anyhow::Error: From<T::Error>`.

---

This one is quite subtle.

You might have expected the desugaring of `?` to be like (ignoring extra facility like the `Try` trait):

```rust
let out_str = match input.try_into() {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return Err(Into::into(e)),
};
```

But it is not. Rather, it is more like:

```rust
let out_str = match input.try_into() {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e)),
};
```

Which produce the exact same error(s). This is because [`Result` uses `From` to convert the error, not `Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/result.rs.html#2106).

Now, having a `From` impl implies having an `Into` impl - because of [the blanket implementation `impl<T, U: From<T>> Into<U> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#541-552) - but the opposite is not true, and moreover, cannot be true with the current Rust trait system.

If `Result` would use `Into` in the desugaring, you'd have been fine, because the compiler can prove `T::Error: Into<anyhow::Error>` holds from your `where` clause, but given it uses `From`, the compiler cannot prove `anyhow::Error: From<T::Error>` holds, and thus raises an error.

There was an attempt to change the desugaring in the past ([#60796](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/60796)), but unfortunately it caused too much inference breakage, so it is probably impossible by now. See:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/84277#issuecomment-903944296
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436#issuecomment-299482914
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436#issuecomment-619427209
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38751

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem, and the explanation is truly helpful and expand my rust knowledge.

Comment: @sofx It was a surprise for me too :) I always thought it is actually using `into()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, your example is missing a `use anyhow::Result`, because `Result` without a `use` is `std::result::Result`, which takes two generic parameters.

The reason why it doesn't compile is because [`Into` can be derived from `From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#impl-Into%3CU%3E), but `From` cannot be derived from `Into`. And the `?` operator seems to use `From`.

Versions which do compile:

```rust
where
    T::Error: std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static,
```

```rust
where
    anyhow::Error: From<T::Error>,
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Compiler is using ```From``` for the ```?``` operation, I thought ```Into``` and ```From``` is equal, but not.

Comment: They are connected, but still different. everything that implements `From` automatically implements `Into`. So it's recommended that you use `From` if you try to write an `impl` for it.