# Formatting errors in a generic TryInto implementation

Tags: generics, rust, anyhow

I am trying to make a generic implementation of `TryFrom` for an object `T` whenever `T` implements a `TryFrom`. However, I am struggling to pass `anyhow::Error`s.

In the code below, I can convert a `Generic<T>` into a `ValueContainer` so long as `&usize: TryFrom<T>`. It *almost* does what I want, but does not allow me to properly handle errors from the `&usize: TryFrom<T>`.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod question {
    use std::fmt::Debug;

    use anyhow::anyhow;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Generic<T: Debug>(T);
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Foo(usize);
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct ValueContainer<'a>(&'a usize);

    impl TryFrom<Foo> for &usize {
        type Error = anyhow::Error;

        fn try_from(value: Foo) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            if value.0 > 5 {
                Ok(&5)
            } else {
                Err(anyhow!("Value must be bigger"))
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T> TryFrom<Generic<T>> for ValueContainer<'a>
    where
        for<'b> &'b usize: TryFrom<T>,
        T: Debug,
        for<'b> anyhow::Error: From<<&'b usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error>,
    {
        type Error = anyhow::Error;

        fn try_from(value: Generic<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            // XXX: Can't do this?
            // let value: &usize = value.0.try_into().unwrap();
            match <&usize as TryFrom<T>>::try_from(value.0) {
                Ok(v) => Ok(ValueContainer(v)),
                Err(_) => {
                    // XXX: I would like this to be the error from the try_into above
                    // but there is an error `<&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error` cannot be formatted with the default formatter`
                    return Err(anyhow!("Error converting type"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_try_into() {
        let value = Generic(Foo(10));
        let value: Result<ValueContainer, anyhow::Error> = value.try_into();
        dbg!(&value);
        let value = Generic(Foo(2));
        let value: Result<ValueContainer, anyhow::Error> = value.try_into();
        dbg!(&value);
    }
}
```

I am not able to use `value.try_into()?` in my implementation of `TryFrom<Generic<T>>`. Uncommenting the `let value: &usize = value.try_into()?;` produces the error

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&usize as TryFrom<Generic<T>>>::Error == <&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error`
   --> lib-doenetml-core/src/core/props/prop_view.rs:140:40
    |
140 |              let value: &usize = value.try_into()?;
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^ expected `Infallible`, found associated type
    |
    = note:         expected enum `Infallible`
            found associated type `<&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error`
    = help: consider constraining the associated type `<&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error` to `Infallible`
    = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

It seems like [Using TryInto generics with anyhow::Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626885/using-tryinto-generics-with-anyhowerror) might be relevant, and it inspired me to add `for<'b> anyhow::Error: From<<&'b usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error>`, but that didn't seem to work...

Any ideas on how I can allow `value.try_into()?` directly?

Comment: Why doesn't your code work? Please add the complete error message from i.e. `cargo build` to your question as [formatted](/help/formatting) text!

Comment: Note that it is better to use `Into` and `TryInto` than `From` in bounds, to be strictly more general.

Comment: You forgot to add `.0`.

Comment: The compiler probably tells you exactly what bound to add to get it to compile.

Comment: @cafce25 The code above compiles. It is the `XXX` in the comments that don't work when uncommenting. For example, on uncommenting the first one I get an error `error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving <&usize as TryFrom<Generic<T>>>::Error == <&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can you explain more? The referenced question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626885/using-tryinto-generics-with-anyhowerror suggests that the bound should be stated in terms of `From` and _not_ in terms of `Into`, specifically related to how `Result` works.

Comment: *"the **complete** error message"* – please add it.

Comment: @cafce25 I have added the complete error message to the question.

Comment: If you add the forgotten `.0` (`value.0.try_into()?`) it works. You seem to ignore what I said, so I'm reposting it here.

Comment: Since you seem to continuously ignore my comments or misinterpret them for some reason, here's a proof that what I suggested works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=195fb5cc4c4676923b4f6cc97d314f8c.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you! That was indeed an error. I've fixed it and have updated the question. It seems that `value.0.try_into()?` works but `value.0.try_into().unwrap()` gives an error `<&usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error doesn't implement Debug`

Comment: That's because `unwrap()` requires the error type to implement `Debug`. Add the bound `for<'b> <&'b usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Debug` and it'll work. However I was under the impression that you want `?`, not `unwrap()`. Anyway, this question should be closed as "was caused by typo".

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The question was not caused by a typo. I did make a typo when creating the minimal example above, but there wasn't a typo in the code I extracted it from. I wanted both `?` and `.unwrap()` to work, but I thought they were both failing for the same reason, so I only put one in the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. Valid then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` will work if you will fix your typo and add `.0`.

`unwrap()` requires the `Debug` trait for the error (because it prints it on failure), so you need to add this bound:

```rust
impl<'a, T> TryFrom<Generic<T>> for ValueContainer<'a>
where
    for<'b> &'b usize: TryFrom<T>,
    T: Debug,
    for<'b> anyhow::Error: From<<&'b usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error>,
    for<'b> <&'b usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Debug,
{
    type Error = anyhow::Error;

    fn try_from(value: Generic<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        // XXX: Can't do this?
        let value: &usize = value.0.try_into().unwrap();
        Ok(ValueContainer(value))
    }
}
```